# Kernel and Image of a map on $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

> I am working on the polynomial ring with two variables $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and trying to find the kernel and image of the map below
>   $$\alpha: \langle y \rangle^{r+1} \oplus \langle x \rangle^{r+1} \oplus \langle y \rangle^{r+1} \oplus \langle x \rangle^{r+1} \to \langle x,y \rangle^{r+1}$$ defined by $\alpha(f,g,h,t) = -f-g-h-t$.

I think $\operatorname{Im} \alpha = \langle y \rangle^{r+1} \oplus \langle x \rangle^{r+1}$ but I need some help about the kernel. Thanks.

Comment: When you write $\langle y\rangle^{r+1}$, do you mean the $r+1$st power of the ideal $y\mathbb{R}[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes, I mean the (r+1)-st power of the ideal which is generated by y. And r is a positive integer

Comment: user26857, can you please give me some hint to see the kernel? 
What I have tried is writing $f=ay^{r+1}$, $g=bx^{r+1}$, $h=cy^{r+1}$, $t=dx^{r+1}$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and if $(f,g,h,t) \in ker \alpha$, then $(-a-c)y^{r+1} = (b+d)x^{r+1}$. Here I have stucked.

Comment: @AlexSanchez From where you stopped we can continue like this: $y^{r+1}\mid (b+d)$ and $x^{r+1}\mid (a+c)$ so $b+d=y^{r+1}w$ and $a+c=-x^{r+1}w$. This shows that $\ker\alpha=\{(y^{r+1}a,x^{r+1}b,y^{r+1}(-a-x^{r+1}w),x^{r+1}(-b+y^{r+1}w)):a,b,w\in\mathbb R[x,y]\}$, and therefore $\ker\alpha$ is generated by $(y^{r+1},0,-y^{r+1},0)$, $(0,x^{r+1},0,-x^{r+1})$, and $(0,0,-x^{r+1}y^{r+1},x^{r+1}y^{r+1})$.

Comment: @user26857, that is what I needed, thank you so much

Comment: Last question, is my guess true for the $Im \alpha$ ?

Comment: No, the image is not a direct sum. For example, $(xy)^{r+1}$ belongs to both the direct summands, but go to the same element in $(x,y)^{r+1}$.